# Resolving C++ undefined references from dlls(so's)

Tags: c++, linux, dll, undefined-reference

I am trying to build a module for ns3 and I am getting undefined references from the generated dynamic libraries .Here is what I am doing to build using waf on my linux box:

The output I am getting can be seen here: http://www.blikoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/wafBuild-Error-1024x244.png

I do know the location of these missing references on my pc but can't figure out how to make the generated dynamics libraries aware of that.Can anyone help figure out.I thought that by making sure the proper headers are included in your source files,you would not have these issues.Why is it the *.so files that are missing the files?Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Read [Drepper's paper: How to Write a Shared Library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

the information to linker about the symbols expeorted  is passed via the makefile. Check your makefile to see if it has the lines for your library symbols.